# Extract pandas dataframes containing specific strings in column names or table entries

Tags: python, pandas, append

I have the following dataframes in python

```
dataframe_list= []## CREATE AN EMPTY LIST
import pandas as pd

A=pd.DataFrame()
A["name"]=["A", "A", "A"]
A["Query"]=["B", "B", "B"]


B=pd.DataFrame()
B["name"]=["A", "A", "A"]
B["Col"]=["query", "B", "B"]

C=pd.DataFrame()
C["name"]=["A", "A", "A"]
C["Col"]=["C", "B", "B"]

 dataframe_list.append(A)
 dataframe_list.append(B)
 dataframe_list.append(C)
```

The list of dataframes contain 3 dataframes in this toy example. I would like to obtain a list of dataframes containing the word query either as a column name or as a table entry. IHow do I accomplish this. I tried the following loop

```
dataframe_list2=[]

for i in dataframe_list:
      
for column in i:
    try:
            m1=i[column].str.contains('query').sum()
            column = column.lower()
            m2 = column.count("query")
            mel_count = m1+m2
    except:
        pass
    
    dataframe_list2.append(i)
```

This however results in a a list with duplicate entries. I want each table to be mentioned just once. Is there a simple elegant solution for this.

Comment: if the only problem is duplicate entries, why not use ```set(list)```

Comment: Not sure what you want to do. Do you want to _filter_ dataframes that have string "query" _either_ in their column names or in an individual cell?

Comment: Yes I want to filter the columns containing string Query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehension with test each column in [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) if contain `query` or test if column name contains too and filter by `if`:

```
dataframe_list2 = [x for x 
                   in dataframe_list 
                   if x.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('query')).any().any() or 
                   any(x.columns.str.lower() == 'query')]
print (dataframe_list2)
[  name Query
0    A     B
1    A     B
2    A     B,   name    Col
0    A  query
1    A      B
2    A      B]
```

Loop alternative is:

```
dataframe_list2=[]

for x in dataframe_list:
    m1 = x.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('query')).any().any()
    m2 = any(x.columns.str.lower() == 'query')
    if m1 or m2:
        dataframe_list2.append(x)

print (dataframe_list2)
```